# Getting return data from subprocess.run

Tags: python, subprocess

I want to get the return data (not return code or output) from suprocess.run. I want to get the returned output and return it as JSON response from an API call. I currently have it set up as below but this only gives me what object_tracker.py prints not what it returns. I've read through some documentation but I'm still not sure how to do this.

```
res = subprocess.run(['python', './model/yolov4_deepsort/object_tracker.py', '--video', './model/yolov4_deepsort/data/video/test_0.mp4', '--model', 'yolov4', '--dont_show'], capture_output= True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `subprocess.check_output` in-order to directly get the output.

If you want to stick using `subprocess.run` function, you should provide the `capture_output=True` parameter and use the `.stdout` property from the `subprocess.run` function.

Here is an example.

```py
import subprocess

run = subprocess.run(["ls"], capture_output=True)

print(run.stdout.decode("utf-8"))
```

Example for `subprocess.check_output`

```py
import subprocess

run = subprocess.check_output(["ls"])

print(run.decode())
```

The `decode` function is used to turn the output into somewhat more readable format, you could try removing the decode function and understand how the output would look like !